# Docker: Cannot locate specified Dockerfile error

Tags: nginx, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I want to make a platform for web development on my PC (MacOS) by using docker. After installing nginx in docker container, I wanted to build nginx. I got this error.

```
Cannot locate specified Dockerfile:nginx.docker
```

I searched on the Internet, but I cannot solve my problem.

Container information (docker ps -a):

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                           NAMES
2f268b825ba3        nginx:latest        "nginx -g 'daemon off"   39 minutes ago      Up 39 minutes       443/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8081->80/tcp   dockertutorial_nginx_1
```

This is my docker-compose.yml file:

```
nginx:
    container_name: dockertutorial_nginx_1
    build: .
    dockerfile: nginx.docker
    ports:
        - 80:8081
    links:
        - php
    volumes:
        - .:/Users/user/docker-tutorial

php:
    image: php:7.0-fpm
    expose:
        - 9000
    volumes:
        - .:/Users/user/docker-tutorial
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Your compose file contains the line `dockerfile: nginx.docker`. Do you have such a file, and what does it contain?

Comment: Yeah, yeah. Dockerfile was wrong location. I solved it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it with the location of Dockerfile. The docker cannot find dockerfile. That's why, I got this error. Btw, thanks to @harald Nordgren.